# Find the seller user id and buy user id located in different states

Tags: sql

I am trying to find the following below.

" Find the seller user id and buy user id such that the buyer has bought at least one item from the seller but the buyer and seller are located in different states."

I tried the following code but i don't think its right. I am attaching a picture of my tables to this post. I don't think the state is correct here.

```
select selleruserid, buyeruserid
from sales_fact
where EXISTS (select b.userid
from buyers_dim b, sellers_dim s
where b.state <> s.state)
```

[Tables]

[image: 1]

Comment: What does the top seller have to do with the maximum price?

Comment: Yeah i dont think that was right. I should be using a SUM here?

I was trying to use the below but i dont think this is right. I can see other ids that have bigger totals. 

select selleruserid
from sales_fact
where price = (select max(price) from sales_fact)

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use comma in the `FROM` clause.  In this case, you can get the pairs of such buyers and sellers using:

```
select sf.selleruserid, sf.buyeruserid
from sales_fact sf join
     buyers_dim b
     on sf.buyeruserid = b.userid join
     sellers_dim s
     on sf.sellersuserid = s.userid
where b.state <> s.state;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want buyer's all the transaction who have made atleast one inter-state transaction then you can use your existing query with correlation as follows:

```
select selleruserid, buyeruserid
from sales_fact sf
where EXISTS (select b.userid
from buyers_dim b join sellers_dim s on b.state <> s.state
  and B.userid = SF.buyeruserid and sf.sellersuserid = s.userid)
```